# How can I explicitly declare a variable of some Phaser type?

Tags: typescript, types, typeerror, phaser-framework, brunch

I am attempting to use [Phaser](https://phaser.io/) with [Brunch](https://brunch.io/) and [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) using `samme`'s [`brunch-phaser2`](https://github.com/samme/brunch-phaser2/tree/typescript) skeleton, but I am running into a `TypeError`:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/samme/brunch-phaser2.git --branch typescript
$ cd brunch-phaser2
$ npm install
$ npm run start

> a-phaser-game@0.0.1 start /home/sam/github/samme/brunch-phaser2
> brunch watch --server

13:49:11 - info: application started on http://localhost:3333/
13:49:12 - error: Compiling of app/initialize.ts failed. TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
Stack trace was suppressed. Run with `LOGGY_STACKS=1` to see the trace. 
13:49:12 - info: compiled 5 files into 2 files, copied 3 in 1.5 sec
```

A slightly different `TypeError` appears in [my Phaser experimention repo](https://github.com/samestep/phaser-nonsense/tree/type-error) when I add an explicit type to my `game` variable:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/samestep/phaser-nonsense.git --branch type-error
$ cd phaser-nonsense
$ npm install
$ npm run start

> @ start /home/sam/github/samestep/phaser-nonsense
> brunch watch --server

13:56:42 - info: application started on http://localhost:3333/
13:56:42 - error: Compiling of app/initialize.ts failed. Error: Error 2503: Cannot find namespace 'Phaser'. (Line: 3, Col: 13)
Stack trace was suppressed. Run with `LOGGY_STACKS=1` to see the trace. 
13:56:42 - info: compiled 2 files into vendor.js, copied index.html in 1.3 sec
```

But in either case, when I change this:

```
const game: Phaser.Game = new Phaser.Game({});
```

to this:

```
const game = new Phaser.Game({});
```

the `TypeError` goes away.

**Why does this explicit type declaration cause a `TypeError` to occur, and how can I resolve the error without removing the explicit type declaration?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Brunch TypeScript plugin doesn't support proper resolution of references ([documentation](https://github.com/brunch/typescript-brunch#errors)).  Their recommendation is to add `plugins: { brunchTypescript: { ignoreErrors: true } }` to your `brunch-config.js` and separately run `tsc --noEmit -p .` to check for errors.